# Change TextColor of one specific MenuItem in ActionBar from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, styles, menuitem, textcolor

I am having trouble to change the text color of a **single** MenuItem (not in an overflow menu, no icon, just text) from inside a Fragment while some condition x is true. I either need to be able to set the style of a single Item and change it during runtime, or change it's color programmatically.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_account_edit, menu);
    ((MultiPanelActivity) getActivity()).setToolbarBackButtonVisibility(!Globals.isTablet());
    if (mightBeChanges) {
        //TODO implement active state with {android.R.attr.textColorSecondary}
    } else {
        //TODO implement inactive state with {R.attr.colorContrastDark}
    } 
}
```

I'd be glad if somebody could provide an approach, that I get to work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I had to change onPrepareOptionsMenu the way Geethakrishna Juluri suggested,
but I also had to add a line, to put the menuItems title into the TextView.

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu aMenu) {
    final MenuItem menuItem = this.menu.findItem(R.id.user_id_label);                               
    final TextView textView = (TextView) menuItem.getActionView();
    textView.setTextColor(SOME_COLOR);
    textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(aMenu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change in onPrepareOptionsMenu. See if it works

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu aMenu) {
final MenuItem menuItem = this.menu.findItem(R.id.user_id_label);                               
final TextView textView = (TextView) menuItem.getActionView();
//set color with condition
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(aMenu);
```

}

Comment: After adding **app:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"** to the menuitem in the xml I was able to use your code, but the MenuItem didn't show up in the actionbar anymore

Comment: I found this was the only thing that worked (to a degree) when using a menu explicitly on a Fragment. Every other suggestion either recolours all items or only applies to a menu on an activity.

Unfortunately, while setting the Color red it just goes grey on my devices.